# Localhost Firebase Cloud Functions are working with the emulator but not live

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase app with an App Check debug token implemented.

When I run my Cloud Functions using the Emulator they work fine.

But when I turn off the emulator and try to access the live deployed version from http://localhost:8080/ I get this console error:

```
POST http://localhost:5001/my-app/us-central1/getZohoDeskTicketsLoggedInUser net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Why does this happen when calling the live version and not with the emulator?

There are no Firebase Cloud Function logs to provide because the functions never even fire.

Perhaps I need to white list the locahost domain somewhere?

Comment: Have you hard-coded `http://localhost:5001` as API URL in your code by chance? When you deploy your website to Firebase hosting or any, you must use URL of deployed Cloud function and not localhost.

Comment: That was my first thought also. I checked the functions `index.js` file and it is not hard coded there. And I checked the caller, also not hard coded there either. Not sure where else to look.

Comment: You were right! I had this in my Firebase config file `connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, 'localhost', 5001);`. Thanks, if you want to make it an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deploy your web app to productions, you should use URL of deployed Cloud function to make your API requests instead of localhost which will lead to connection errors. You can additionally call `connectFunctionsEmulator` only when you are on localhost:

```
if (window.location.hostname === "localhost") {
  connectFunctionsEmulator(...)
}
```